# Android java add content

Tags: java, android, arrays, database

Let's say I uploaded an application which shows Film titles.
(In code it is an array of those titles)

What would be the best way to update the Film titles list dynamicly,

would I have to change my code and upload the application again or is there a way around it like a database.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a file somewhere in the internet (you can just use something like Dropbox or Git to host it) and have your program open it (that should work just like opening a file on your computer, just make sure that you don't try to write it) and read the information from there

Comment: create a BufferedReader from the URL (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("http://www.example.com/abc.def"))), then you can read each line in the file with br.readLine()